# C/C++/C# SetWindowPos: Window on top of others

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi

I would like someone to give a working example of [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx) on how to make a window "topmost" (be on top and stay there) using either C/C++/C#. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is wrong with the MSDN example?

Comment: indeed, the answer is in front of your nose :)

Comment: The exact method will be quite different between C/C++ and C#, so you should probably specify which of the three you're planning to use.

Comment: @Erik: Both are acceptable
@Naveen and Pieter888: What MSDN example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SetWindowPos with .NET](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowPos)

Answer (score 4):

C/C++:

```
// This doesn't size or move the window, just makes it top-most.
SetWindowPos( hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );
```

Comment: I do not understand this, how do I tell it which application to be on top?

Comment: The hWnd parameter specifies the window that should be moved to the top.

Answer (score 1):

C#

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: This will not help for other windows except the application form.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue a while ago, and asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808505/wpf-in-kiosk-mode-taskbar-troubles).  The actual details of my issue were probably not the same as yours, but just in case, I'll summarise my question and the answer.

I needed to keep a particular (WPF) application foremost all the time it was running to attempt to deny access to other software on the machine.  I ended up running a timer every 1/4 second that makes a call out to user32.dll's `SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd)` method to grab focus to the app, along with setting `TopMost = true` on my window.

HTH